# JSON to array of values in Python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file that has a large number of key:value data. How can I create an array of just the values in the JSON (in the order of the JSON list).

What I've got so far:

```
inputJSON = open('input.json')
inputData = json.load(inputJSON)
```

inputData is an array where each element in the array is key:value. How can I instead get an array where each element is just the value?

Comment: Please show a sample of your JSON file/data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you load the json you are actually converting it into a python dictionary. You can then simply show all values:

```
inputJSON = open('input.json')
inputData = json.load(inputJSON)
values = list(inputData.values())
```

Comment: It's not a dictionary if the file is actually a JSON list

Answer (score 0):

If `key:value` is in plain text, you can do:

```py
values = [pair.split(":")[1] for pair in inputData]
```

If by `key:value` you mean a dict type `{key: value}`, you can do as follows:

```py
values = [list(pair.values())[0] for pair in inputData]
```